# docker compose build fails with IO timeout

Tags: docker

I have installed WSL 2.0 and my version of docker is

```
Client:
 Cloud integration: 1.0.17
 Version:           20.10.7
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.4
 Git commit:        f0df350
 Built:             Wed Jun  2 12:00:56 2021
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true
```

When I try to do a build of an image I get the following error

```
Error response from daemon: i/o timeout
```

Comment: A simple web search shows various solutions. Which of these have you tried? There are various issues with Docker for Windows that sometimes happen, especially after upgrade or a previous installation not cleaned up.

Comment: There is this open issue on github: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/12907

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Open "Window Security"
2. Open "App & Browser control"
3. Click "Exploit protection settings" at the bottom
4. Switch to "Program settings" tab
5. Locate "C:\WINDOWS\System32\vmcompute.exe" in the list and expand it
6. Click "Edit"
7. Scroll down to "Code flow guard (CFG)" and uncheck "Override system settings"
8. Delete all files from C:\Users<name>\AppData\Roaming\Docker
9. Start vmcompute from powershell "net start vmcompute"

For more info: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4413

Comment: I tried this but still got the error. Then I uninstalled docker desktop and installed it once again, and It worked

Comment: I've just ran docker desktop with admin rights and it worked. This was also suggested in the link above.

Comment: Doesn’t this reduce security?

Comment: I just restarted my laptop, it worked without issues...

Comment: System error 5 has occurred. Access is denied

Comment: In my case `vmcomputer.exe` was not in the list. Adding it to disable CFG would be nonsensical, because if it's not in there, CFG is already not enabled for the executable. This solution works in specific scenarios, it is not a general fix.

Answer (score 6):

This happened when i put my windows laptop to sleep
When i tried to resume in the morning, i was greeted with the error above.

Restarting Docker resolved it for me

I hope this helps